# Path To Image Not Found in Bootstrap Popover

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap

This is driving me crazy. I have a small image, and I want to display a larger version when the user hovers their cursor over it. So, I have this:

```
$("#Portrait").popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: function () { return '<img src="~/Images/person.jpg" width="100" />'; }
})

<img src="~/Images/person.jpg" width="50" id="Portrait" class="img-circle img-responsive hidden-xs" />
```

This isn't exactly how I want it to work, but I've simplified it a lot to try and make it work and it still won't. As you can see, the page to the image is identical in the jQuery function and in the HTML markup. When the page loads, the image displays correctly, but in the popover I just see the image placeholder that you get when the image path is incorrect.

If I replace the code for the image in the function, whatever I write displays correctly in the popver, so the code to populate the popver with HTML is working. When I replace the path to the image in the function with a URL to an online image, that image displays correctly in the popover.

The problem seems to be very specifically with the path to the image in the function. It fails to work both when debugging on my machine and after publishing to the web server. I've tried moving the image to the same folder as the page so that the path can simply be `person.jpg`, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please put your running code into a jsfiddle.net so people can help you better, and faster ;)

Comment: I was going to, but since the problem only manifests itself when I'm trying to display an image using a relative path to a folder on the web server, I don't see how I can.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't fully understand why, but I'm guessing that reliance on the tilde (~) to specify application root is a bad habit I've carried over from coding in ASP.NET. Anyway, I fixed this problem by using the Url.Content helper to get the correct path to the image, like this:

```
$("#Portrait").popover({
    html: true,
    container: 'body',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: function () {return '<img src="' + "@Url.Content("/Images/person.jpg")" + '" width="100" />'; }
})

<img src="~/Images/person.jpg" width="50" id="Portrait" class="img-circle img-responsive hidden-xs" />
```